# What is the simplest instruction set with a current supported toolchain?

Tags: llvm

I am planning as an exercise to learn Verilog to implement a CPU core. As this is my first time doing it, I am wondering what would be the simplest CPU architecture with a currently supported toolchain that could be implemented.

The list of supported architectures can be seen here:

[CompilerWriterInfo](https://llvm.org/docs/CompilerWriterInfo.html)

I learned about the [ZPU](https://opencores.org/projects/zpu) which is extremely simple but the compiler support is outdated (need to compile a very old gcc from sources).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSP430 ISA contains just 27 instructions. There are multiple toolchains around, original one from TI as well as msp43-gcc and MSP430 support in LLVM/clang.